# OpenVPN can't resolve host name with DNS set up

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, openvpn

*This is most likely a duplicate, but I can't find the correct solution for my problem*

I set up a OpenVPN server on our NAS and added `push "dhcp-option DNS 10.66.0.4"` (this is a random ip, I set it up with our correct DNS).

Now all the mac clients using tunnelblick can connect to it and also ping the NAS by it's hostname. Without the option that wasn't possible and I had to ping the NAS via IP.

I hoped that would be the same on windows, but it's not.

What do I have to do to make windows resolve hostnames? I tried to change the adapter settings, but that didn't do the trick. Also adding `dhcp-option DNS 10.66.0.4` to the client config didn't work ether.

So how can I set up the windows client to resolve hostnames instead of IP adresses?

These are the settings in the client config:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
nobind
pull
resolv-retry infinite
key-direction 1
redirect-gateway def1
script-security 2
comp-lzo
reneg-sec 0
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
```

And also `dev tap` isn't an option here.

Comment: Does `10.66.0.4` represent a Windows DNS server, or a Linux bind host?  Is there a firewall between your OpenVPN/NAS server, and `10.66.0.4`?

Comment: @leeharvey1 I use the DNS from our router. For mac clients it's working. The only firewall that' in between is the windows firewall itself and the firewall of our router on which the DNS is running on.